# modifying vim paragraph jumping commands to whitespace-containing lines or code blocks

Tags: vim

1) With the { and } commands in vim I can jump to the previous or next completely blank line (or beginning or end of file). How do I modify these commands to jump to the previous or next line being completely blank or containing only whitespace (or beginning or end of file) ?

2) How do I create commands to jump to the beginning or end of the current code block, defined by the current indent? For example, I want to easily move from line F to line D or G (or to line C or H):

```
A
  B
  C
    D
    E
    F
    G
  H
I
```

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it's not complete enough, but for #2 you can use the indent() function to get the indent of the current line, then use that indent in a search expression to find the next line with the same indent. I did something similar in a plugin to jump between labels in a C switch statement which you can find at http://vim.sourceforge.net/script.php?script_id=511 if some example code might help.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 seems relatively easy (and my answer probably a bit naive):

```
nnoremap } /^\s*$<CR>
nnoremap { ?^\s*$<CR>
```

But you should find another shortcut, I think.

Also you already have `gg` to jump to the first line of the buffer and `G` to jump to its last line. Isn't that enough?

I don't know how to answer question 2 in a simple manner. Did you try [vim-indent-object](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3037)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. vim-indent-object was more or less exactly what I was looking for the second question. For the first question, I came up with a similar solution myself but then the search highlighting gets triggered and it doesn't look too nice (although I guess I could turn it off). Also, the fact that the { and } commands can jump to the beginning/end of the file is quite handy... It would be great if there is a way to get that functionality.

Comment: I don't like it so I don't activate highlighting (it's off by default).

Comment: @Matt: The contents of the search register are restored after a function call. Therefore you can put your search commands within a function, set your mapping to call that function and when the function returns, your cursor will have moved but your search highlighting will be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the great tips of romainl and garyjohn I got the exact functionality I was looking for for part #1:

```
nnoremap <silent> { :call MyPrevParagraph()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> } :call MyNextParagraph()<CR>

function MyNextParagraph()
  let myline = search('^\s*$', 'W')
  if myline <= 0
    execute 'normal! G$'
  else
    execute 'normal! '.myline.'G0'
  endif
endfunction

function MyPrevParagraph()
  let myline = search('^\s*$', 'bW')
  if myline <= 0
    execute 'normal! gg0'
  else
    execute 'normal! '.myline.'G0'
  endif
endfunction
```